# How can i keep the dot in a string while removing letters from the alphabet

Tags: python, string, slice

I have a string: `lst = 'sbs1.23444nroen'`
im using `lst2 = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, lst))` to remove all the letters so the result is: `lst2 = '123444'`
is there any way to include the "." so that the result would be '1.23444' without the letters but keeping the dot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more friendly to the eye solution and extendable if you want to include more characters.

```py
s = 'sbs1.23444nroen'
toKeep = set('0123456789.')
s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch in toKeep)
print(s)
```

Comment: also very interesting because you can manually choose it easily, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
lst2 = ''.join(filter(lambda x: str.isdigit(x) or x=='.', lst))
```

Comment: @Hdsa I do not get that error.

Comment: Note that you could also just use `x.isdigit()`.

Comment: it had 'l' instead of 'or' before it was edited. now its fine. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use a regular expression, although the `set` solution is the best so far.

```py
>>> re.findall(r"\d+\.\d*", lst)
['1.23444']
```

With the added benefit of grabbing other groups of numbers as well:

```py
>>> re.findall(r"\d+\.?\d*", "sbs1.23444nroe631n")
['1.23444', '631']
```